Google Cloud Job logs splitting single line log into multiple lines
I am running a python script in GCP cloud jobs and the logs are getting weirdly split into multiple lines. Pretty much unreadable. Is there a way to avoid this
log = getLogger()
log_formatter = Formatter(
    "[%(process)d] [%(threadName)s] %(asctime)s %(name)s: %(message)s"
)
for handler in log.handlers:
    handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)

log.setLevel(INFO)

The below log prints as a single line in my local console


This is a known bug. Take a look at Google's public issue tracker. You can also check out this related SO post for a workaround.

Thanks, I was aware of them. But they were very specific about error stack logs splitting. And there are comments there stating the same

Also its worthy to note the timestamps are different between the split logs
